# Look up account name based on number in map on visualforce page

Tags: apex

I have a (work in progress) formula that will get a customer name based on a account number provided by third party member via a visualforce page. I have it all mapped out so All i need is to get the account number via visualforce page and get the corresponding name. 
Does anyone know how to do this ?

```
public void showaccount(){

list<Account> aclist =   [SELECT Id, Name, Customer_Account_Number__c FROM Account];
Map<Id, Account> m = new Map<Id, Account>(aclist);

System.debug(m.values());
System.debug(m.size());    
m.values();
m.size();    
}
```

and the visualforce page :

```
<apex:form id="frma">
      <h3> Lookup account </h3>
      <p> Type in the account number to get the name of the account that way you can always stay on top of the game.
                      </p> 


                    <apex:inputText id="username" html-placeholder="Account Number" styleClass="form-control" value="{!uano}"/>

                      <apex:commandButton value="Show Account" action="{!showaccount}" status="status" styleClass="btn btn-default" rerender="frma"/>

                      </apex:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want to display account name when the user provides the account number in the textbox and hit show button. I am not sure why you are querying all the accounts. Here is the code that may help you.

```
<apex:page  controller="testcls">
<apex:form id="frma">
      <h3> Lookup account </h3>
      <p> Type in the account number to get the name of the account that way you can always stay on top of the game.
       </p> 
    <apex:inputText id="username" html-placeholder="Account Number" styleClass="form-control" value="{!uano}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Show Account" action="{!showaccount}" status="status" styleClass="btn btn-default" rerender="frma"/>
    <apex:outputText  id="ddder">{!accName}</apex:outputText>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And the class:

```
public class testcls{
public string uano{get;set;}
public string accName{get;set;}
public void showaccount(){
accName = '';
AccName = [Select Name, Customer_Account_Number__c from Account where Customer_Account_Number__c =:uano limit 1].Name;  
}  
}
```

This is just a heads on to give you an idea. You have to put validations and throw catch statements as per your needs.

Comment: Can you tweak the query logic a bit? An account number that didn't match (a fairly common case) would cause the "List has no rows for assignment to SObject" error.

Answer (score 1):

Shailesh's approach is better than querying for all the accounts. However, if you want to use the Map for some reason, you could try using the code below

Page:

```
    <apex:page  controller="testcls">
        <apex:form id="frma">
            <h3> Lookup account </h3>
            <p> Type in the account number to get the name of the account that way you can always stay on top of the game.
            </p> 
            <apex:inputText id="username" html-placeholder="Account Number" styleClass="form-control" value="{!uano}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Show Account" action="{!showaccount}" status="status" styleClass="btn btn-default" rerender="frma"/>
            <apex:outputText  id="someId">{!accountName}</apex:outputText>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Class:

```
    public class someClass{
        public string accountName{get;set;}
        public string uano{get;set;}
        public void showaccount(){
            list<Account> accountList =   [SELECT Id, Name, Customer_Account_Number__c FROM Account];
            Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account>(accountList);

            System.debug(accountMap.values());
            System.debug(accountMap.size());
            accountMap.values();
            accountMap.size();
            accountName = (accountMap.get(uano)).Name;
        }
    }
```